# Ruby Session Always Spawns New Session (sudo)

Tags: ruby, shell, sudo

I have some simple code which creates a Session object (using the [session gem)](http://rubygems.org/gems/session) to run some shell commands.  I am using sudo multiple times within the same BEGIN block and I am getting prompted on every command for the sudo password.  I believe it should only be asked for the first time after the Session is created and then reuse the session to avoid this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'rubygems'
require 'date'
require 'mysql2'
require 'session'


begin
  sh = Session::Shell.new
  puts "Starting file system copy."
  $WWW_ROOT = "~/Downloads/"
  $MASTER='/git/library/dev/.git'
  $DOMAIN = ARGV[1].to_s
  $DOC_ROOT = [$WWW_ROOT, $DOMAIN].join

  stdout, stderr = sh.execute ("cd #{$WWW_ROOT} && ls && sudo git clone -q #{$MASTER} #{$DOMAIN}")
  if stderr.length > 0
    puts stderr
    puts 'Error on git cloning.'
  else
    puts stdout, stderr
puts "Git cloning finished."    
  end

  stdout, stderr = sh.execute ("cd #{$DOC_ROOT} && sudo git checkout lib_dev")
  if stderr.length > 0
    puts stderr
    puts 'Error on Git lib_dev checkout.'
  else
    puts stdout, stderr
puts "Git lib_dev checkout finished."   
  end

end
```

**How can I make the *sudo* password prompt only occur once?**

Comment: Sorry if I'm not quite getting the problem, but what about invoking the *entire script* as superuser, so that there will be no need for `sudo`s inside it? I mean `sudo ./your_file.rb` instead of `./your_file.rb`?

Comment: +1 @NIA, using `sudo` to call the script is preferred. The script can check to see the effective and actual user it's running as, and abort with an error if it's not got the right privileges.

Comment: well, I am taking over a project from another programmer and he warned me that the overall script shouldn't be called that way because he ran into issues with making the file system usable with the web server.  I don't know more than that but I guess I need to try it and see what happens.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of issuing "sudo" for every command which the *session* must run as root, have the session switch to *root*, just once:

```
sh.execute "sudo su"
```

Make sure to keep that instance of the session around.  Now leave of the "sudo" prefix to the commands you run with the session.

```
sh.execute "cd #{$WWW_ROOT} && ls && git clone -q #{$MASTER} #{$DOMAIN}"
...
sh.execute "cd #{$DOC_ROOT} && git checkout lib_dev"
```

If your script must do some things and root and some as the user, then keep around *two* sessions, only one of which is root:

```
user_sh = Session.new
root_sh = Session.new
root_sh.execute "sudo su"
user_sh.execute "some_ordinary_command"
root_sh.execute "some_command_needing_root_privileges"
```